# Can I create Windows Desktop x86 application on M1 mac?

Tags: wpf, windows, winforms, xamarin.forms, apple-m1

I own M1 MacBook and I need to create windows desktop app that will work also on windows surface and other intel machines as desktop application. I know there is WPF and windows forms (used them on windows machines in the past) to do that or some others like xamarin or whatever but is there way to create such app that will be cross platform ? Or can I use some virtual machine on M1 to create such app that can run on intel machines ? Is there any acceptable way to do it ?

If it's not possible using .net frameworks can I create windows desktop application using any other framework (using some other language like kotlin, java, C++ or whatever) on M1 mac?

Comment: You could look into Avalonia or .NET MAUI.  If you know HTML and CSS, you could use Blazor Hybrid.

Comment: If you intend to use C# Xamarin is cross platform or ASP.Net Core if you want a web app.

Comment: @DarkTemplar I am not asking anywhere about web apps

Comment: @adv12 Looks like you answered this question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research it look like it's not possible to create intel windows executable on M1 cpu at all. So basically you need two computers to do that.

> As @adv12 wrote in comment looks like Avalonia is good choice but I
> didn't tested it yet or .NET MAUI and also possibly Flutter desktop
> could work.  There is no way of building .net widow forms or WPF looks
> like even on virtual machine as they also run in ARM mode.
>
> Sure you can also go for old school Java JRE but thats kind of
> outdated way and will not give great user nor developer experience I
> believe.

Comment: Flutter desktop cannot do that

Comment: Will be happy if someone corrects me.

Comment: While you can feel free to accept your own answer, `dotnet publish -r win-x86 --self-contained` is commonly used to generate Windows binaries on any machine. You never need "two computers" in many cases. But you cannot publish WinForms/WPF because of another reason, that Microsoft didn't want to ship those parts of .NET SDK on non-Windows platforms.

Comment: @LexLi Yeah thats cool but I detail in question that I am asking about WinForms/WPF application creation without windows hardware, to be specific to create it on my mac, so thats not posible. Anyway quastion closed, someone don't likes it.

Comment: "I am asking about WinForms/WPF application" isn't true as you expanded the question scope much broader than merely WinForms/WPF (and likely why it was closed). At least, Avalonia allows you to publish Windows binaries from Mac. And there can be other options.